# Usage of ControlsFX AutoCompletion SuggestionProvider

Tags: java, autocomplete, controlsfx

I am working on the implementation of the ControlsFX autocompletion/suggestion in a small JavaFX desktop application.

I am unable to compile following code:

```
SuggestionProvider<String> provider = SuggestionProvider.create(list); 
AutoCompletionBinding acbLogin = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchField, t -> {
new AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding<>(searchField, provider);return list.stream().filter(elem -> {
                            return elem.toLowerCase().startsWith(t.getUserText().toLowerCase());
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    });
```

Getting following error

```
cannot access class impl.org.controlsfx.autocompletion.SuggestionProvider (in module org.controlsfx.controls) because module org.controlsfx.controls does not export impl.org.controlsfx.autocompletion to module com.example.test
```

Got a similar error when I implemented ControlsFX `AutoCompletion` library and could fix it with following code in the pom.xml in the maven-plugin-section

```
<options>
    <option>-XX:+UseG1GC</option>
    <option>--add-exports</option>
    <option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls</option>
</options>
```

Any ideas if there is similar troubleshooting available?
Appreciate your help.
Many thanks.